# CSS stylesheet doesn't work with Spring Security + Spring Boot + Thymeleaf

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

After much research, I haven't been able to find a solution. I have a project implemented with Spring Boot + Spring Security + Thymeleaf.

I have a REST API multi-module project and a web client built with Thymeleaf. My problem is that I can't seem to include my CSS stylesheet in my Thymeleaf page.

MvcConfig :

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.
                addResourceHandler(
                "/css/**",
                "/img/**").
                addResourceLocations(
                        "classpath:/resources/static/img",
                        "classpath:/resources/static/css");
    }
```

My Html (Thymeleaf)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <title>Bibliothèque d'OC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/static/css/style.css}">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

I've tried changing the value of the path set on the `th:href` attribute of the `link` tag (`th:href="@{/static/css/style.css}"`). And I've also tried adding an `href` attribute to the `link` tag; neither one helped. I can't find the solution.

Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: „*…I tried to change my Path…*“ –  @Jqk3 — What „*Path*“ are you referring to? Where in your code snippet, exactly?  — „*…or add an href…*“  — Same question. To what did you „*add an href*“? TIA.

Comment: I try like this  : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/static/css/style.css}" href="/static/css/style.css" media="all">

And just change this :  th:href="@{/static/css/style.css}"

Comment: „*…And just change this : th:href="@{/static/css/style.css}"…*“ — What did you change that *from*? That is, what was it *originally*? Or if your reply refers to what that attribute was *originally*,  then what did you change *`th:href="@{/static/css/style.css}"`* *to*?

Comment: I just tried several urls

Comment: „*I just tried several urls*“ — Have you tried any of [*the suggestions I've proposed*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64170736/4465539)? What is your project's directory structure? That's a very important detail that you have not yet made clear. Your reply can be in this format: „*`…/src/blah/foo/bar/…`*“. TIA.

Comment: Incidentally, yesterday I managed to reproduce the issue described in your question even without your feedback. More importantly, I now know precisely what the solution is. But I shall take your silence as an indication that you have also found the same solution by now. Were you as surprised as I was by the root cause of the problem? Do you intend to share your solution? In case you weren't aware: *You are allowed to post an answer to your own question*. You'd be helping others who might search for a similar solution in the future. TIA.

Comment: Hello, sorry for my late response, I was away.
I have tried your urls but nothing works.
My project structure is:

Comment: resources
  |____static
            |____css
                       |_____styles.css

Comment: „*I have tried your urls but nothing works*“ — I assume you mean the three links in the footnotes. Have you implemented ***any*** of [*the suggestions I've proposed*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64170736/4465539): «*in addition to the `th:href` attribute and `th` namespace declaration suggestions — remove that unnecessary `registry.addResourceHandler( … )` configuration*»? Why does this feel like I am pulling teeth?

Answer (score 1):

***TL;DR*** — Change *`th:href="@{/static/css/style.css}"`* to *`th:href="@{/css/style.css}"`*.

---

***The long-winded version***

Thymeleaf expects projects to have a particular, default directory structure: *`src/main/resources/static`*. The *path* that you set for Thymeleaf's special *`th:href`* attribute ***must*** be relative to that expected directory structure.<sup>*1*</sup>

The snippets in your original question and your replies in the comments, suggest that your project is laid out like this…

```sh
…
└───src
    └───main
        │
        └───resources
            ├───static
            │   └───css
            └───templates
```

If that is the case, then the relative path to your stylesheets that you need to give to Thymeleaf should be: *`th:href="@{/css/style.css}"`*.

If that is *not* the case and your project's directory structure is something different than what I illustrate above then please share, in the comments of this answer, what exactly your directory structure is.

I noticed that you declare the Thymeleaf *`th`* namespace twice; once in the *`html`* tag, then again in the *`head`* tag. There should be only one namespace declaration.<sup>*2*</sup> My advice is that you remove the one in the *`head`* tag.

Consider this from a 2013 blog post on spring.io…<sup>*3*</sup>

> > *…Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories*:
> >
> > - *`/META-INF/resources/`*
> > - *`/resources/`*
> > - *`/static/`*
> > - *`/public/`*
> >   …

According to that, not only is this part of your application's configuration unnecessary, I have a hunch that it could be the root cause of your problem…

```java
…
registry.
        addResourceHandler(
        "/css/**",
        "/img/**").
        addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/resources/static/img",
                "classpath:/resources/static/css");
…
```

I've implemented *at least* a dozen different Spring Boot applications that served static content. I've never once had to implement any configuration code like you are doing there.

My advice is — *in addition to the `th:href` attribute and `th` namespace declaration suggestions* — remove that unnecessary *`registry.addResourceHandler( … )`* configuration.

---

<sup><sup>*1*</sup></sup> <sup>[*Add CSS and JS to Thymeleaf*](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-css-js#2-adding-css) — *Amy DeGregorio*</sup>
<sup><sup>*2*</sup></sup> <sup>[*Using Thymeleaf*](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#a-multi-language-welcome) — *Official documentation*</sup>
<sup><sup>*3*</sup></sup> <sup>[*Serving Static Web Content with Spring Boot*](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) — *Spring Blog*</sup>